# Detect 'enter key' press in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my case i need to scan barcode and fetch product details. Normally barcode scanner devices emit `enter key(keycode=13) event` at end of scanning, But in flutter enter key is not same as `Done` so how can code to detect enter key pressed in my TextFormField widget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TextFormField(
maxLines: null,
autovalidate: true,
   validator: (value){
             if(value.contains('\n')){
              doFun(value);
              }   
            }

)
```

When user press `enter key` new line create in text box. We check with that.

`maxLine:null` - to hide multiline

`autovalidate:true` -to automatically run validator fun

`'\n'` - new line ('\s'-whitespace,'\t'-tab.. etc)

Comment: This solution almost works for me - the problem is that with maxLines = null, the text field grows when you hit Enter.  Any way to make it stay one line tall (without losing the '\n')?

Comment: @Lars335 were u able to solve it in case maxLines=null

Answer (score 62):

if you are using `TextField` then you have to add `onSubmitted` in your text field to detect when user press **Enter** key. For my case, I changed `Done` in keyboard to `TextInputAction.Search`. It also works for `TextInputAction.Done` too. here is a sample code

```
   TextField(
    onSubmitted: (value){
      //value is entered text after ENTER press
      //you can also call any function here or make setState() to assign value to other variable
    },
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
  )
```

Comment: When I try to use this (On Flutter Web), and I tap the enter key on my physical keyboard, the only thing that happens is the TextField loses focus. Any ideas why this may not work?

Comment: @ShawnAshton I'm sorry that I couldn't help you on this as I never tried flutter web yet!

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS if you're using the native number input: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/139304

Answer (score 23):

The solution above works, but I believe `RawKeyboardListener` is a more reliable and flexible solution. You just need to cover the text field with it and start to listen to keyboard events:

```
var focusNode = FocusNode();
RawKeyboardListener(
        focusNode: focusNode,
        onKey: (event) {
          if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
            // Do something
          }
        },
        child: TextField(controller: TextEditingController())
    )
```

As a second option you can use `onKey` method of the `FocusNoded` and pass the node to your text field:

```
var focusNode = FocusNode(onKey: (node, event) {
    if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
        // Do something
        // Next 2 line needed If you don't want to update the text field with new line.
        // node.unfocus(); 
        // return true;
    }
    return false;

});
TextField(focusNode: focusNode, controller: TextEditingController())
```

Comment: The first solution looks good to me but how does it trigger 'onSubmitted' of the TextField when the enter key is pressed?

Comment: Update: I see. I moved the function from the 'onSubmitted' of the TextField to 'Do something' block in your suggestion. And I supplied it with the text from the TextEditingController in the TextField. Works great.

Comment: ...but only for physical keyboards.

Comment: Since `onKey` will be deprecated soon, is there an equivalent way of doing this with `onKeyEvent`? It doesn't seem to recognize `enter`.

Comment: I agree to @RiversCuomo, I am debugging using laptop, and it could not listen to keyboard enter key, other keys are logged except it.

Comment: I get `The return type 'bool' isn't a 'KeyEventResult', as required by the closure's context.` for the `onKey` handler.

Comment: The 2nd example needs updating to`return KeyEventResult.handled;` and `return KeyEventResult.ignored;` respectfully.

Answer (score 12):

In case someone is looking for the same solution (as Al Walid Ashik) but for `TextFormField`, just use the following:

```dart
TextFormField(
  /// ...
  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
     /// do some stuff here
  },
),
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the form field losing focus when implementing this?

Comment: That sounds like another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492002/flutter-how-to-keep-textfield-focus-on-submit

Answer (score 4):

In  addition to the Sergey Yamshchikov's answer:

In case if it is a multiline TextField (maxLines: null) and you want to catch up the entered key and prevent passing it into the text field, you can use this approach:

```
RawKeyboardListener(
    focusNode: FocusNode(onKey: (node, event) {
              if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
                return KeyEventResult.handled; // prevent passing the event into the TextField
              }
              return KeyEventResult.ignored; // pass the event to the TextField
            }),
    onKey: (event) {
      if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
        // Do something
      }
    },
    child: TextField(controller: TextEditingController())
)
```

But, if you need to detect the keys combination, like ctrl+enter, then you can use CallbackShortcuts:

```
CallbackShortcuts(
  bindings: {
    const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter, control: true): _doSomething(),
  },
  child: Focus(
    autofocus: true,
    child:  TextField(controller: TextEditingController()),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This helped me as it lets you have a multi line textField and stop it adding a new line when you press enter!

Comment: `RawKeyboardListener` is not working in iOS