# Flutter, RawKeyboardListener to get text after Enter key press

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app where I need to look up details after a barcode has been scanned into a TextFormField (using a physical Android mobile device).  The scanner  just sends the barcodes as keyboard input (with '\n' at the end).

I am using a RawKeyboardListener and it works fine when I manually enter text and press enter, however, the scanner sends the keystrokes at a much higher rate and the TextEditingController is still empty when the Enter key arrives at the RawKeyboardListener.

I am currently using a Future.delayed to wait 500 ms before trying to read the text and this works, but I do not like this solution very much (too fragile):

```
handleKey(RawKeyEvent event) {
  var isEnter = event.logicalKey.keyId == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter.keyId || event.logicalKey.keyId == 1108101563381;
  if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent' && isEnter) {
    print('- Text: ' + _textController.text);                 <--- Empty here
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      print('- Text after delay: ' + _textController.text);   <--- '013803266986' here
    });
  }
}
```

**My question:** What is a more robust method to get the scanned barcode (text) after the Enter key?

Here is a full runnable sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _textNode = new FocusNode();

  handleKey(RawKeyEvent event) {
    var isEnter = event.logicalKey.keyId == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter.keyId || event.logicalKey.keyId == 1108101563381;
    if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent' && isEnter) {
      print('- Text: ' + _textController.text);
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        print('- Text after delay: ' + _textController.text);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 300,
          child: RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: FocusNode(),
            onKey: (event) => handleKey(event),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _textController,
              focusNode: _textNode,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: This method does not work for me (since it makes the text field grow): [Detect 'enter key' press in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860198/detect-enter-key-press-in-flutter)

Comment: I will withdraw my answer as it doesn’t solve your question. However I recommend you update the question with the link to the issue track and explain that you are looking for a workaround as the api has a bug, not for the official way it should work.

Comment: RawKeyboardListener seems to have issues with focus when used with TextField. Here's an open issue on GitHub https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67915

Answer (score 0):

A more robust way to delay code until the next framework tick would be [WidgetsBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/scheduleFrameCallback.html). Pass your closure here instead of Future.delayed.

---

Also may be worth trying the [Shortcuts](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextEditingShortcuts-class.html) class instead of RawKeyboardListener; following [this example](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextEditingShortcuts-class.html).

I just discovered it and generally seems like it could replace RawKeyboardListener for a lot of solutions.